# How to add several groups of toolbar using qml?

Tags: qt, qt4, qml, qt5

Is there a way to add several groups of toolbar in Qt based application using qml? For instance, there is a toolbar called `StandToolBar`, which contains `newToolButton`, `openToolButton`, `saveToolButton`, `saveAsToolButton` and `saveAllToolButton`. And there is another toolbar called `EditToolBar`, which contains `copyToolButton`, 'cutToolButton', `pasteToolButton`, `undoToolButton` and `redoToolButton`.

Comment: I don't think you can have more than one `ToolBar`. You can implement your own or you can put several containers/layouts inside `ToolBar` to obtain the desired result. That said, `ApplicationWindow` consider the toolbar to be a unique `Item` like stated in the [documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-controls-applicationwindow.html#toolBar-prop).

Comment: @BaCaRoZzo When using C++ code, you can easily add as more `ToolBar` as you can just as following code does. So I want to know how to do it using qml instead.

    QToolBar *standToolBar = addToolBar(tr("&File"));
    standToolBar->addAction(openAction);

    QToolBar *editToolBar = addToolBar(tr("&Edit"));
    editToolBar->addAction(copyAction);

Answer (score 1):

You can do :

```
import QtQuick 2.2
import QtQuick.Controls 1.2
Item {
    width:800
    height: 480
    ToolBar {
        id:standToolBar
        Rectangle{
            color:"lightgrey"
            anchors.fill: parent
        }

        Row {
            anchors.fill: parent
            ToolButton {
                id:newButton
                text: "new"
                // iconSource: "new.png"
            }
            ToolButton {
                id:openButton
                text: "open"
                // iconSource: "open.png"
            }
            ToolButton {
                id: saveButton
                text: "save"
                // iconSource: "save.png"
            }
            ToolButton {
                id: saveAsButton
                text: "save as"
                // iconSource: "save-as.png"
            }
            ToolButton {
                id: saveAllButton
                text: "save all"
                // iconSource: "save-all.png"
            }

        }
    }
    ToolBar {
        id:editToolBar
        anchors.top: standToolBar.bottom
        Rectangle{
            color:"lightgrey"
            anchors.fill: parent
        }

        Row {
            anchors.fill: parent
            ToolButton {
                id:copy
                text: "copy"
                // iconSource: "copy.png"
            }
            ToolButton {
                id:cut
                text: "cut"
                // iconSource: "cut.png"
            }
            ToolButton {
                id:paste
                text: "paste"
                // iconSource: "paste.png"
            }
            ToolButton {
                id:undo
                text: "undo"
                // iconSource: "undo.png"
            }
            ToolButton {
                id:redo
                text: "redo"
                // iconSource: "redo.png"
            }

        }
    }
}
```

### Edit

To get them in a `row` I removed all `anchors` and assigned a `width` for `Toolbar` :

```
import QtQuick 2.2
import QtQuick.Controls 1.2
Item {
    width:800
    height: 480
    Row{
        spacing: 5
        ToolBar {
            id:standToolBar
            width:400
            Rectangle{
                color:"lightgrey"
                anchors.fill: parent
            }

            Row {
                //  anchors.fill: parent
                ToolButton {
                    id:newButton
                    text: "new"
                    // iconSource: "new.png"
                }
                ToolButton {
                    id:openButton
                    text: "open"
                    // iconSource: "open.png"
                }
                ToolButton {
                    id: saveButton
                    text: "save"
                    // iconSource: "save.png"
                }
                ToolButton {
                    id: saveAsButton
                    text: "save as"
                    // iconSource: "save-as.png"
                }
                ToolButton {
                    id: saveAllButton
                    text: "save all"
                    // iconSource: "save-all.png"
                }

            }
        }
        ToolBar {
            id:editToolBar
            width: 400
            Rectangle{
                color:"lightgrey"
                anchors.fill: parent
            }

            Row {
                //  anchors.fill: parent
                ToolButton {
                    id:copy
                    text: "copy"
                    // iconSource: "copy.png"
                }
                ToolButton {
                    id:cut
                    text: "cut"
                    // iconSource: "cut.png"
                }
                ToolButton {
                    id:paste
                    text: "paste"
                    // iconSource: "paste.png"
                }
                ToolButton {
                    id:undo
                    text: "undo"
                    // iconSource: "undo.png"
                }
                ToolButton {
                    id:redo
                    text: "redo"
                    // iconSource: "redo.png"
                }

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why doesn't putting both toolbars into a `Row` work?

Comment: I dont know, yes it's strange, I'll take a look to the source code of Toolbar, You can use anchors as a workaround

Comment: Lol. It was an `Item`...it's getting too hot here. I'm saying stupid things.

Comment: @Mitch The answer above really works well that `standToolBar` is on the top of `editToolBar`. But if you want to putting the `editToolBar` on  the right of `standToolBar` with `anchors.left: standToolBar.right`, it doesn't work since `standToolBar` has full fill the parent. We may need a better solution in order to put both toolbars in a `Row`.

Comment: putted a new code, the row issue was that the Toolbar have the width of the window, to solve it you should assign a width to it, like in my edited code :)